# Javascript and Python - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a Django blog, and i'm a beginner, so I am still learning from tutorials on the internet.

I found sample program with Javascript on the Internet, and base on the program i want to implemented filter by category in my project.

This is the javascript code [link](https://pastebin.com/6Xhh37Jt),
and this is my django file

**views.py** `https://pastebin.com/SVy8B0k5`

**index.html** `https://pastebin.com/RJ6R9Pjv`

forgive me to use link to show the code, because the code is very long.

as far as I know my solution is to create class for JS like `post_search_text` in the code.

But i don't know how to write JS code, please help me

Thank you

Comment: All you want to know is about managing static files in django. You can read it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Please, show some pieces of code related to the javascript that you used. Don't show all of the code cause basically all your problem have same fixing pattern.  show one function in views and the template.